# toroidal compactifications of modulis spaces of ppav's

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, toric-varieties, compactifications

Are the modular toroidal compactifications of ppav's (second Voronoi) defined by Alexeev without self-intersections? i.e. are the irreducible component of the boundary divisor normal? If not, can one find another toroidal compactification (possibly dominating the second Voronoi) that is?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some links will help attract more activity.